# Reading input file and processing it in flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to write a simple flask program that will create a web page in which it receives a file (by uploading it), and then using that file's data and displaying a filtered part of it in my web page, I just cant seem to understand how to do that.

This is the code I used to upload the file, which worked fine.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'C:/Users/ohadt/PycharmProjects/logFiles'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'log'])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit a empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect(url_for('read_uploaded_file',
                                    filename=filename))
    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <p><input type=file name=file>
         <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''
```

Then I tried writing the method for opening the file and reading the data from it, but I couldn't figure how to do that, could you please help me understand how to read the file content and presenting a filtered version of it on my site?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You already saved it here

```
file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
```

just open it up and read as you work with any other files, example:

```
@app.route('/read_file', methods=['GET'])
def read_uploaded_file():
    filename = secure_filename(request.args.get('filename'))
    try:
        if filename and allowed_filename(filename):
            with open(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)) as f:
                return f.read()
    except IOError:
        pass
    return "Unable to read file"
```

You need to carefully sanitize user input here, otherwise method could be used to read something unintended (like app source code for example). Best is just not grant user ability to read arbitrary files - for example when you save a file, store it's path in database with some token and give user just this token:

```
filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
filepath = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
file.save(filepath)
token = store_in_db(filepath)
return redirect(url_for('read_uploaded_file',
                                   token=token))
```

Then accept a token, not a filename when you read a file:

```
@app.route('/read_file', methods=['GET'])
def read_uploaded_file():
    filepath = get_filepath(request.args.get('token'))
    try:
        if filepath and allowed_filepath(filepath):
            with open(filepath) as f:
                return f.read()
    except IOError:
        pass
    return "Unable to read file"
```

Tokens need to be random, long, not guessable (uuid4 for example) - otherwise there will be a possibility to easily read other users files. Or you need to store relation between file and user in database and check it too. Finally, you need to control size of file uploads to prevent user from uploading huge files (`app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH']`) and control amount of info you read in memory when you display "filtered" file content (`f.read(max_allowed_size)`).